# Received memory warning

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I am working on an app with xml parser, uiwebview, navigationcontroller, displaying a lot of images on the main controller, that remains in the memory throughout the whole life of the app. I store my data using core data.
I tried to figure out the memory footprint of the application since I am getting the following warnings:

> Received memory warning. Level=1   app delegate received memory
> warning   main controller received memory warning   main controller
> received memory warning   RSSItem received memory warning
>
> Received memory warning. Level=2   app delegate received memory
> warning   main controller received memory warning   main controller
> received memory warning   RSSItem received memory warning

The footprint is around 4MB, and jumps up to around to maybe 10 when I drill down and display UIWebViews with a significant number of images.
Is that footprint too large? I assume that there are apps out that are considerably more complicated. From what I understand the apps have 40-70MB available, give or take, but definitely not 10MB limit. Anyone has any insight what can I do to fix it or work around the problem. I do not have leaks.
I am afraid that the real problem is not the footprint but something else I am not aware of.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have memory analysis tools in Instruments.app - this will show you much data related to allocations in your app.

if i had to guess: destroy images which are not visible.

Comment: Thanks Justin. Definitely it's a good idea to minimize memory usage if possible, and I am working on that. But still, 3-10MB is not that much. In the meantime I just uncommented the [super didReceiveMemoryWarning] in didReceiveMemoryWarning. It seems to work, although I am sure this is not the right way to fix the problem.

Comment: yw. also, you *should* call through `super` in your override. call through `super` first if you don't need specific behaviour.