# iPad App Crashes After Loading 30+ Images

Tags: ios, image, crash, uiimageview

Is there a reason the ipad crashes and restarts after loading 30+ images quickly in an image view using this code:

```
else if([webData isEqualToString:@"ppt33"]){
    if(movieisplaying == @"yes"){
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"33.png"];
        [imageView setImage:image];
        [moviePlayerController stop];
        [moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
        movieisplaying = @"no";
    }
    else{
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"33.png"];
        [imageView setImage:image];

    }
}
```

EDIT:
Crash Error - **2012-07-26 13:48:55.172 Stream[5554:707] Received memory warning.**

Comment: Can you post the error that you get when it crashes?

Comment: @KarolyS sure it's in my edit

Comment: Hmmm, how big are your images? Can you try loading say 25? 20? Try to find the maximum you can load before it crashes.

Comment: @KarolyS I have about 40 images and 4 videos, the app doesnt crash with the videos but after about 32 pictures it crashes. Is there any way to 'destroy' and image if it is not in use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are all the images and videos in use/visible constantly? From the warning it sounds like you may be exceeding your allotted memory for you app.

This question seems to be related, [Received memory warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018456/received-memory-warning) though it does not detail how to destroy images not in use. I would say try to be smart about when you are loading what image, and then release an image if you are no longer using it. Same goes for the videos. Hope that helps!

EDIT: You could do something like this:

```
NSMutableArray * imageArray;

imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

UIImage *oneImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"33.png"];
[imagesArray addObject:oneImage];
[oneImage release];
//Add the remaining images, could probably turn this into a for loop
```

Alternatively, before you give that a shot, you could try to do `[image release]` after everything in your else statement that you provided.

Comment: Each time the image changes I use this code (with a different filename): `UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"34.png"];
            [imageView setImage:image];`
I use similar code for the videos, but the images are the problem; is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: I'm having trouble picturing what may be causing this for you, because at first glance, what you've written seems correct. What I would try if I was in your position, is to load all 40 images into a UIImage Array in your viewDidLoad, or wherever, and then just do your     [imageView setImage:imageArray[34]]; The reason is, is that I have a feeling that if you were to run a memory monitoring tool, you would see yourself repeatedly creating images, without removing unused ones. How big is each image in memory, roughly?

Comment: the images range in size from 0.5mb to 1.2 mb, how would I create the UIImage array?

Comment: @Nathan Niamehr Hmm, you may want to try to compress them, I think the 1.2 mb ones may be hurting you. I've also updated my answer with some more things to try.